# A question regarding the comparison test for a particular series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I came across this question and was able to get the right answer using the comparison the first time around, however a friend of mine solved it also using the comparison test but in a slightly different way and got a different answer. I'm unable to see how their answer is any wrong
We are asked to check the convergence of the following series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$
I took the n-th term of this series to be $u_n=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ and $v_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{u_n}{v_n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} =1(finite)$$
Which implies that $u_n$ and $v_n$ must converge or diverge together

Now let $w_n= \frac{1}{n}$
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{u_n}{w_n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1} =0(finite)$$
Hence $u_n$ and $w_n$ must also either converge or diverge together

However, $v_n$ converges while $w_n$ diverges which leads to a contradiction

Comment: $0$ must be excluded. In fact, if you would have chosen $\frac{w_n}{u_n}$ , the limit would not have been finite.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is of course correct, however, the reason for why the second part is not, is because $c$ - the limit of the ratio - has to be strictly positive. To elaborate on @Peter's comment, the limit comparison test is symetric, in the sense that both series ($a_n,b_n$) either converge or diverge together. So if the limit test works for $a_n/b_n$, then it should also work for $b_n/a_n$. And in your case, $w_n/u_n=n+1$ diverges.